# Using gatsbyJS for site where contents update often

Tags: gatsby, server-side-rendering

I was interested in using gatsbyJS in one of my hobby projects. I've read a little about it and had some quick questions around if it was a good fit. The project has around 30-50 routes (including the / route) where content updates every 15 or 30 mins. Currently i use react to server side render the pages and send them back to the browser.

I've read that gatsbyJS generates a static version of the site (and there is no node server involved as such). Does this mean the page wont be server side rendered, and the content that needs to be updated is basically rendered on the client (after fetching data from the server)?

Is gatsbyJS a good fit for projects where content changes often? Can gatsbyJS be used to basically deliver the same server side rendered experience?

Answer (score 1):

> Does this mean the page wont be server side rendered, and the content that needs to be updated is basically rendered on the client (after fetching data from the server)?

With Gatsby, pages are server-side rendered during build time (resulted in static html with data baked in), then 'rehydrated' on the client side. You can choose to re-build pages every time there's new data (cron jobs, web hook, etc.) or render pages with a default data, then update the data on the client side.

> Is gatsbyJS a good fit for projects where content changes often? Can gatsbyJS be used to basically deliver the same server side rendered experience?

It could be! Depending on how images are handled + your choice of cloud builder, it can takes a few minutes, half an hour or more to build your site. For a site that get updated often, this means user might get slightly outdated data (though you can still fetch new data on the client side to mitigate this.)

The trade-off is that the time to render on the client side can be very fast, since it's static html. Also depending on the source of data, you may not have to maintain a server (i.e say your data comes from scraping or 3rd-party API, you can scrape/fetch data and then render Gatsby site).